# Cannot generate equals and hashcode in Intellij for scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

When I right click and select Generate, I only see Delegate methods and Test. Am I missing something in my installation?

```
class Person(val firstName : String){}
val person = new Person("Srinivas")
```

In the same project, I created a java class and everything works fine. Definitely IntelliJ is missing something for Scala. Any help in troubleshooting will be appreciated.

Edit: I figured it works fine in a Scala class (can see all options for creating a hashcode and equals method), but does not work in a worksheet.

Comment: Maybe you are missing something. When did you first install the Scala plugin for IntelliJ? In my case, it was earlier this year, right along the initial installation of IntelliJ. I made a `Person` class just like in your example, right-clicked and it created `equals()`, `hashCode()` *and* `canEqual()`.

Comment: I know!!! Just found out it woks fine in Scala class but not in a worksheet

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot. Kind of like how probably neither the local Scala REPL nor Scastie would either.

Answer (score 4):

Don't you see this option? [image: picture]

However, in your case, it's preferred to convert this class to  [case class](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html), so you don't need to generate equals or hashcode - it's all built-in.

```
case class Person(firstName: String)
val person = Person("Srinivas")
```

Comment: When I select generate, I only get Delegate methods and Test. Although I figured that it works like yours in a Scala class but does not work in a Worksheet. I agree that a case class is a simpler option, was just trying to see why this is not working.

Comment: Interesting, I just checked it with Worksheet and it works as well.